# Python: Nested Loop

Tags: python, loops, nested

Consider this:

```
>>> a = [("one","two"), ("bad","good")]

>>> for i in a:
...     for x in i:
...         print x
... 
one
two
bad
good
```

How can I write this code, but using a syntax like:

```
for i in a:
    print [x for x in i]
```

Obviously, This does not work, it prints:

```
['one', 'two']
['bad', 'good']
```

I want the same output. Can it be done?

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you're trying to do.  Your second example has an implicit loop via a list generator.  Is your issue simply that you don't want to have two `for` loops following each other for aesthetic reasons?

Comment: Personally, I think the loop you already have is the best way to do this.  It's simple, clear and readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> a = [("one","two"), ("bad","good")]
>>> print "\n".join(j for i in a for j in i)
one
two
bad
good



>>> for i in a:
...  print "\n".join(i)
... 
one
two
bad
good
```

Answer (score 7):

List comprehensions and generators are only designed to be used as expressions, while printing is a statement.  While you can effect what you're trying to do by doing

```
from __future__ import print_function
for x in a:
    [print(each) for each in x]
```

doing so is amazingly unpythonic, and results in the generation of a list that you don't actually need.  The best thing you could do would simply be to write the nested `for` loops in your original example.

Comment: It should also be noted that this will only work in Python 2.6 or 3

Comment: much better off using the answer that **tgray** provided rather than this

Comment: the print function really is awesome, however I think there is a much superior way to use it (hence my answer).

Answer (score 7):

Given your example you could do something like this:

```
a = [("one","two"), ("bad","good")]

for x in sum(map(list, a), []):
    print x
```

This can, however, become quite slow once the list gets big.

The better way to do it would be like [Tim Pietzcker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20670/tim-pietzcker) suggested:

```
from itertools import chain

for x in chain(*a):
    print x
```

Using the [star notation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments), `*a`, allows you to have n tuples in your list.

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools
for item in itertools.chain(("one","two"), ("bad","good")):
    print item
```

will produce the desired output with just one `for` loop.

Comment: This works but I'm guessing (although not positive) that in his real code he has **n** number of tuples, not a predefined set that he can hardcode.

Comment: To see what I'm getting at, read tgray's answer, with the `*a` notation.

Answer (score 3):

The print function really is superior, but here is a much more pythonic suggestion inspired by Benjamin Pollack's answer:

```
from __future__ import print_function
for x in a:
    print(*x, sep="\n")
```

Simply use `*` to unpack the list x as arguments to the function, and use newline separators.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define your own print method (or import `__future__.print_function`)

```
def pp(x): print x

for i in a:
  _ = [pp(x) for x in i]
```

Note the `_` is used to indicate that the returned list is to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

This code is straightforward and simpler than other solutions here:

```
for i in a:
    print '\n'.join([x for x in i])
```

Comment: `print '\n'.join(j for k in a for j in k)`

Answer (score 0):

Not the best, but:

```
for i in a:
    some_function([x for x in i])

def some_function(args):
    for o in args:
        print o
```