# Merge Two wordlists into one file

Tags: linux, merge, brute-force

I have two wordlists, as per examples below:

**wordlist 1 :**

```
code1
code2
code3
```

**wordlist 2 :**

```
11
22
23
```

I want to take **wordlist 2** and put every number in a line with first line in **wordlist 1**

**example of the output :**

```
code111
code122
code123
code211
code222
code223
code311
.
.
```

Can you please help me with how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: What code have you tried so far, and how well has it worked?

Comment: sadly :( i din't try i know how to create a wordlist but not to merge two :(

Comment: Are you familiar with for loops, and nested for loops? This might help. https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: i use loop but it's my first time hearing nested loops thanks for u'r time i'l check the link

Comment: This previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821471/python-nested-loop might be useful to review.

Comment: Are you looking for a `bash` or `python` solution? remove the tag that is not needed

Comment: any solution , i did remove the tag

Answer (score 1):

You can run two nested for loops to iterate over both lists, and append the concatenated string to a new list.
Here is a little example:

```py
## create lists using square brackets
wordlist1=['code1', ## wrap something in quotes to make it a string
           'code2','code3']
wordlist2=['11','22','23']

## create a new empty list
concatenated_words=[]

## first for loop: one iteration per item in wordlist1
for i in range(len(wordlist1)):
    ## word with index i of wordlist1 (square brackets for indexing)
    word1=wordlist1[i]
    ## second for loop: one iteration per item in wordlist2
    for j in range(len(wordlist2)):
        word2=wordlist2[j]
        ## append concatenated words to the initially empty list
        concatenated_words.append(word1+word2)

## iterate over the list of concatenated words, and print each item
for k in range(len(concatenated_words)):
    print(concatenated_words[k])
```

Comment: i have tried to change the list to file but it turn out with an error

Comment: If you have python installed, open a text editor, paste the code example, and save it to a file called `string_concatenation.py` (a python file). Then, open a terminal, navigate to the folder of the file, and type `python string_concatenation.py`. This should print the desired output in your terminal.

Comment: no i mean wordlist2 i want to take it from a file.txt

Answer (score 0):

list1 = ["text1","text2","text3","text4"]
list2 = [11,22,33,44]
def iterativeConcatenation(list1, list2):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(list2)):
        for j in range(len(list1)):
            result = result + [str(list1[i])+str(list2[j])]
    return result

Answer (score 0):

have you figured it out? depends on if you want to input the names on each list, or do you want it to for instance automatically read then append or extend a new text file? I am working on a little script atm and a very quick and simple way, lets say u want all text files in the same folder that you have your `.py` file:

```py
import os

#this makes a list with all .txt files in the folder.
list_names = [f for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if f.endswith('.txt')]
for file_name in list_names:
    with open(os.getcwd() + "/" + file_name) as fh:
        words = fh.read().splitlines()

with open(outfile, 'a') as fh2:
    for word in words:
        fh2.write(word + '\n')
```